# Who is closer, parents to children, or grandparents to grandchildren?

Tags: sources-mekorot, hashkafah-philosophy, love, kerovim-close-relatives

According to Judaism, what relationship is closer: parents to children or grandparents to grandchildren?

What is greater: the love to children or the love to grandchildren?

(Someone asked me and I told him the love to children is greater, but I can not think of sources.)

Comment: Depends on the people involved.

Comment: Love is not a Halachic term, and can not be "ruled". Please decide what's your question about - relations in Halacha or feelings.

Comment: @AlBerko my question is about both, you can make 2 separate answers, (there is regarding hate "ששונאות"
 https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Even_HaEzer.22.10 , and halacha 5 here about love https://www.chabad.org/3302356/ )

Comment: Can you please elaborate on "closer". What constitutes "closeness" for you?

Comment: If the Torah says "ויאהב יצחק את עשיו כי ציד בפיו" can you extrapolate it on all fathers? Also, how do you understand a love for kids - what is it for you? One can give them candies and another train for a marathon.

Comment: @AlBerko what it means to **me** is not important,

Comment: If so, I would flag it as *"not clear what's asked for"*.

Comment: @AlBerko before you do that please help me make it clearer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85145/discussion-between-al-berko-and-hazoriz).

Answer (score 1):

If you can make any inference from inheritance laws (Shulchan Aruch, CM 276) [which is based on next-of-kin], the relationship of parent-son is closer than grandparent-grandson.

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Choshen_Mishpat.276.1?with=Mishneh%20Torah,%20Inheritances&lang=bi

Comment: Why would you make this kind of inference?

Comment: This would imply that a man's relation to his son's son is closer than his relation to his daughter, at least if his son is dead.

Comment: My Grandma and Grandpa(miss 'em both, just under 75 years married) would raise extreme objection to this answer! Grandpa(@97) might have even tricked you and crushed your hand in a handshake just to make his point.

Comment: @msh210 - Only because the inheritance would go to the grandson via the dead son; the grandson is not a closer relative to the grandfather, but the closest relative to the son.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1:**

I would learn it straight from the [Mishna](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Kiddushin.1.7?vhe=Torat_Emet_357&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) and Gemmorah in [Kiddushin 29](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Kiddushin.29a.6?vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=bi):

> "כָּל מִצְוֹת הַבֵּן עַל הָאָב, אֲנָשִׁים חַיָּבִין וְנָשִׁים פְּטוּרוֹת. וְכָל מִצְוֹת הָאָב עַל הַבֵּן, אֶחָד אֲנָשִׁים וְאֶחָד נָשִׁים חַיָּבִין."
>
> All commandments of the son which are upon the father, men are obligated, and women are exempt. And all commandments of the father which are upon the son, both men and women are obligated.

Note, only father-son relations are mentioned.

Later the Gm elaborates on which Mitzvos:

> "תנינא להא דת"ר האב חייב בבנו למולו ולפדותו וללמדו תורה ולהשיאו אשה וללמדו אומנות וי"א אף להשיטו במים:
>
> ... a Baraita: **A father is obligated with regard to his son** to circumcise him, and to redeem him if he is the firstborn son, and to teach him Torah, and to marry him to a woman, and to teach him a trade. And some say: A father is also obligated to teach his son to swim.

Out of the 5/6 Mitzvos listed, the Gm. discusses only one Mitzvah that can apply to grandfather-grandson, which is Talmud Torah.

Therefore I conclude a father is far more concerned with his kids that a grandfather.

Note: this applies only to fathers and sons, not mothers and daughters.

**Option 2:**

One is obligated to say Kaddish after his parents but not after grandparents.

**Option 3:**

One is obligated to financially support his kids but not his grandkids.

**Option 4:**

A son inherits his parents without a Kinyan, as ברא כרע דאבוה, but inheriting other relatives requires a Kinyan.

---

I'm sure there are more.

Comment: +1 maybe see  http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/sh/sh5/6/1/8/index.htm and the next saif http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/sh/sh5/6/1/9/index.htm